# Can I use zoom with ARView?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, realitykit

I would like my user to use zoom in AR application. Is it possible to zoom using ARView?

I have written the following code and added it to tap action.

```
 let discoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes:
        [.builtInTrueDepthCamera, .builtInDualCamera, .builtInWideAngleCamera],
        mediaType: .video, position: .back)
    
    let devices : [AVCaptureDevice]  = discoverySession.devices
    let zoomFactor:CGFloat = 2
    
    for de in devices {
        print("name of camera")
        print(de.localizedName)
        do{
            try de.lockForConfiguration()
            de.videoZoomFactor = zoomFactor
            de.unlockForConfiguration()
        }catch {
            print ("error")
        }
               
    }
```

I run it on IPhone X and see result in log

```
name of camera
Back Dual Camera
name of camera
Back Camera
```

But it has no effect on zoom.

Is it even possible to zoom in while using ARKit?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the camera's zoom with the reality kit. Reality kit uses the camera provided by ARKit and it's fixed with a focal length of 28mm. But you can zoom on the ArView like Andy Jazz's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
// Use ARView as a subview of UIView
@IBOutlet var arView: ARView!


// Set minimumValue and default value of slider to 1
@IBAction func sliderForZooming(_ sender: UISlider) {
    
    // CGAffineTransform 3x3 matrix
    arView.transform = .init(a: CGFloat(sender.value),  b: 0,  c: 0,
                             d: CGFloat(sender.value), tx: 0, ty: 0)
}
```